# Import PDF into LibreOffice Draw results in rectangles / boxes / text missing

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, libreoffice-draw

I have a password-protected PDF which, upon import into LibreOffice Draw (and Microsoft Word, too), shows rectangles / boxes all over the document. Through Google I didn't find **anyone** else with this problem (which in itself makes me wonder why). I've searched for "boxes", "rectangles", "no characters" etc. Does anyone have the slightest idea why this happens?

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the file is password protected, maybe it's not just preventing edits but also copy of text.

That case the behaviour you've experienced is completely normal

[image]